# How to store values from params in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My URL is:

```
location=Berlin&location=Georgia&location=Kopenhagen
```

This URL is generated from the following form:

```
<form action="/posts" method="get">
  <input name="location" value="Berlin" type="checkbox">
  <input name="location" value="Georgia" type="checkbox">
  <input name="location" value="Kopenhagen" type="checkbox">

  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

My Controller is `params[:location]`

Output:

```
Kopenhagen #=> I need all like: Berlin,Georgia,Kopenhagen
```

How can I show all examples like above?

Comment: IIRC, that should be `location[]=Berlin&location[]=Georgia&location[]=Kopenhagen`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to do like this in the html(view).

```
<form action="/posts" method="get">
  <input name="location[]" value="Berlin" type="checkbox">
  <input name="location[]" value="Georgia" type="checkbox">
  <input name="location[]" value="Kopenhagen" type="checkbox">

  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then, in the Controller, you can get `location` like this.

```
location = params[:location] // as array
```

or

```
location = params[:location].join(',') // as string
```

Comment: Yes exactly this is please give me another solution if you don't mind like from this url I need like this `['Berlin', 'Georgia', 'Kopenhagen']` type of output

Comment: do you wantt the output `['Berlin', 'Georgia', 'Kopenhagen']` as a string or array? if string, `params[:location].to_s`, if array, `params[:location]`. it's easier to handle as a array than as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
location=Berlin&location=Georgia&location=Kopenhagen
```

I don't think this is valid URL. You can change your form to

```
<form action="/posts" method="get">
  <input name="location1" value="Berlin" type="checkbox">
  <input name="location2" value="Georgia" type="checkbox">
  <input name="location3" value="Kopenhagen" type="checkbox">

  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then you can access the params[:location1], params[:location2] and params[:location3] seperately

Comment: I have updated my question about this link generate from which

Answer (score 0):

try this `location=Berlin,Georgia,Kopenhagen` and in controller you will got

```
params[:location]= "Berlin,Georgia,Kopenhagen"
```

and you can convert it in array if you want

```
params[:location]= "Berlin,Georgia,Kopenhagen".join(',')
```

Comment: Hi @Pardeep-Saini , I have updated my question about this link generate from which & how can modify this if I'd like to follow your answer